# Display categories of a Custom post type in WooCommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, variable-assignment, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type with own categories.

I would like to link the categories of the custom post type to the WooCommerce product. e.g. This product belongs to the category Fabric cover.

These categories I have displayed in Woocommerce products in the backend.

I do that with getterm. So far, everything works. I then created a checkbox field in front of each category.

When I save the contents, all categories are stored in an array (whether I've selected it or not). I would like to save only the category I have selected. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

**how can I just save the array of the selected checkbox in metabox (pro_in_cat_fields).**

At the moment all values are saved. If I only check one checkbox (for example, fabric cover1), only the values that are in the same array of the checkbox need to be saved. not the values of fabric cover 1, fabric cover 2, ... etc

```php
<?php
add_action('admin_init', 'add_pro_in_cat_boxes', 1);
function add_pro_in_cat_boxes() {
  add_meta_box( 'pro_in_cat-fields', 'Save product in custom category', 'pro_in_cat_meta_box_display', 'product', 'normal', 'low');
 }
    function pro_in_cat_meta_box_display() {
      global $post;
      $pro_in_cat_fields = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pro_in_cat_fields', true);
      wp_nonce_field( 'pro_in_cat_meta_box_nonce', 'pro_in_cat_meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.pro_in_cat_submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#publish').click();
      }); 
    });
      </script>
      <table id="pro_in_cat-fieldset-one" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr> 
          <th width="30%"></th>
          <th width="70%"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    <?php
    $stoffcat_parent= get_terms( 'cover_cat', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 ) );
      if ( $stoffcat_parent ) :
     foreach( $stoffcat_parent as $parent_term ) {
      echo $parent_term->name . '<br>';
    $stoffcat_value = get_terms( 'cover_cat', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $parent_term->term_id ) );
      foreach( $stoffcat_value as $child_term ) {
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="widefat" name="pro_in_cat_status[]" value="<?php echo $checked; ?>"  />
          <input type="text" class="widefat" name="pro_in_cat_name[]" value="<?php if($child_term->name != '') echo esc_attr( $child_term->name ); ?>"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="pro_in_cat_termid[]" value="<?php if($child_term->term_id != '') echo esc_attr( $child_term->term_id ); ?>" />
          <input type="text" class="widefat" name="pro_in_cat_slug[]" value="<?php if($child_term->slug != '') echo esc_attr( $child_term->slug); ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <?php

         } 
      } 
      else :
        // show a blank one
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="widefat" name="pro_in_cat_status[]" />
          <input type="text" class="widefat" name="pro_in_cat_name[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="pro_in_cat_termid[]" /><input type="text" class="widefat" name="pro_in_cat_slug[]" /></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endif; ?>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      <p>
      <input type="submit" class="pro_in_cat_submit" value="Save" />
      </p> 
    <?php
    }
    add_action('save_post', 'pro_in_cat_meta_box_save');
    function pro_in_cat_meta_box_save($post_id) {
      if ( ! isset( $_POST['pro_in_cat_meta_box_nonce'] ) ||
        ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['pro_in_cat_meta_box_nonce'], 'pro_in_cat_meta_box_nonce' ) )
        return;
      if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;
      if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
        return;
      $pro_in_catold = get_post_meta($post_id, 'pro_in_cat_fields', true);
      $pro_in_catnew = array();
      $pro_in_catstatus = $_POST['pro_in_cat_status'];
      $pro_in_catnames = $_POST['pro_in_cat_name'];
      $pro_in_cattermid = $_POST['pro_in_cat_termid'];
       $pro_in_catslug = $_POST['pro_in_cat_slug'];
      $count = count( $pro_in_catnames );
      for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
        if ( $pro_in_catstatus[$i] != '' ) {
          $pro_in_catnew[$i]['pro_in_cat_status'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $pro_in_catstatus[$i] ) );
          }
        if ( $pro_in_catnames[$i] != '' ) {
          $pro_in_catnew[$i]['pro_in_cat_name'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $pro_in_catnames[$i] ) );}
        if ( $pro_in_cattermid[$i] != '' ) {
          $pro_in_catnew[$i]['pro_in_cat_termid'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $pro_in_cattermid[$i] ) );}
        if ( $pro_in_catslug[$i] != '' ) {
          $pro_in_catnew[$i]['pro_in_cat_slug'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $pro_in_catslug[$i] ) );}
    }
      if ( !empty( $pro_in_catnew ) && $pro_in_catnew != $pro_in_catold )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'pro_in_cat_fields', $pro_in_catnew );
      elseif ( empty($pro_in_catnew) && $pro_in_catold )
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'pro_in_cat_fields', $pro_in_catold );
    }
```

Comment: Have you used Custom Post Type UI pluign?

Comment: No, I have taken over the code of the repeatable fields and then adapted.